# force pull docker image in Apache Aurora

Tags: docker, mesos, apache-aurora

I'm trying to launch a Apache Aurora job in a Mesos cluster from a Docker image.

My configuration is:

```
Job(cluster       = 'my_cluster',
    environment   = 'devel',
    role          = 'my_role',
    service       = True,
    constraints   = {
      'aurora-worker': 'true'
    },
    name          = 'my_name',
    instances     = 1,
    task          = mytask,
    container     = Docker(image='my-registry:5000/my_image:latest')])
```

Unfortunately, after the first run the image get cached on the node and is not refreshed subsequently.

Is there a way to force Aurora to pull the Docker image for a given job (similar to Marathon's forcePullImage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, pulling of the image is an optional supported by containerizer in Mesos. More specification [here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/docker-containerizer/#what-does-the-docker-containerizer-do).

I checked the website of Aurora, may be change below would help.  Change `Docker(image='my-registry:5000/my_image:latest')` to `Docker(image='{{docker.image[my_image][latest]')`. Of course with your docker registry configured in `cluster.json` at the same time, which [specified here](http://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/features/containers/#docker-containerizer). Extra infos [here](http://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/reference/configuration/#docker-object).

May this would help.

Comment: It worked! We actually had to amend our registry credential setup, but that was the correct syntax. Thx

Comment: @Jean-MathieuVermosen You could show more details. So I may edit my answer and make it more specific for others who have similar issue.